# ASP.Net Core Razor model validation for a <select> element

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a .Net Core web application and I am trying to get the model validation to work as I want.

The razor code is

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Duration"></label>
      <select asp-for="Duration" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Pick number of days</option>
          <option value="7">7 days</option>
          <option value="14">14 days</option>
          <option value="21">21 days</option>
          <option value="28">28 days</option>
      </select>
      <div><span asp-validation-for="Duration" class="text-danger"></span></div>
  </div>
```

The model is

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "The duration is required")]
  [Display(Name = "Length of audit:")]
  public int Duration { get; set; }
```

If I do not select any value, the drop down remains at "*Pick number of days*". The validation message that is shown is "**The value '' is invalid.**"

Apart from creating my own custom validator, how can I get the code to generate the validation message of "**The duration is required**"

Comment: Have you rebuilt your project?

Comment: yes I have. The issue seems to be the way the different validators work.

Comment: One solution is to use <option value="0">Pick number of days</option> for no selection and [Range(7,28,ErrorMessage = "The duration is required") instead of [Required] for the annotations. I'd prefer to not select a value but it does work.

Comment: yes, to avoid that message due to the string value unable to be converted to `int`, you need to provide a valid `int` first, `0` is the best choice here. Your custom validation then can take on that to run its validation and produce whatever messages you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type for the `Duration` property to a nullable `int`:

```
public int? Duration { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add required to the select list

```
  <select required asp-for="Duration" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Pick number of days</option>
      <option value="7">7 days</option>
      <option value="14">14 days</option>
      <option value="21">21 days</option>
      <option value="28">28 days</option>
  </select>
```